# Moment.js wrong calc from now

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to show the difference between the date I enter and the current one. For this I am doing that:

```
$("#news").append(

            "<h5>"+moment(["2018-03-27 12:18:41"]).fromNow()+"</h5>"

            );
```

However, momentjs prints: '4 months ago' and it is yesterday date

Maybe you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date you mentioned in the question is a date of March, which is definitely not yesterday. Moreover, you need to pass the date string itself to the `moment()` constructor; don't wrap it in an array:

```
moment("2018-03-27 12:18:41").fromNow()
```

MomentJS uses the arrayed format for special cases, where you need to pass year, month, and day as separate integers. Additionally, as @charlietfl mentioned, passing the date format will ensure correct date parsing:

```
moment("2018-03-27 12:18:41", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow()
```